# Get HashMapsValues from nested HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> filtered against a List<String>

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a nested String HashMap and a List of object. The object has a String property to be matched against the values of the inner HashMap.

I'm trying to find a single liner using `stream()` and `Collectors` for the below java code

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>PartDetailsHMap=new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>()
List<Part> partList=new ArrayList<Part>();


for(int i=0;i<partList.size();i++)
    String partId = partList.get(i).getPropertyValue("part_id");
    for(HashMap< String, String> PartPropsHMap:PartDetailsHMap.values())
    {
        if(PartPropsHMap.containsValue(itemId))
        {
            collectingPartMap.put(partList.get(i), PartPropsHMap);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If needed I can extract String property in a `List<String>`.

Looking for a one liner using `stream()`.

Comment: what is the definition of `Part` and where do you get `itemId` from? Is `itemId` same as `partId`?

Comment: This code is a part of a SOA code. Part can be considered as any POJO object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> PartDetailsHMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Part> partList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Part, Map<String, String>> collectingPartMap = partList.stream()
      .map(part -> PartDetailsHMap.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(partPropsHMap -> partPropsHMap.containsValue(part.getPropertyValue("part_id")))
        .findFirst()
        .map(partPropsHMap -> new SimpleEntry<Part, Map>(part, partPropsHMap))
        .get()
      )
      .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

I've used `SimpleEntry` class in `AbstractMap` to carry the context of `Part` along with the map that we've found to the next operation - `collect`.

Caveat: I feel if the option without streams is cleaner and does the job, I would go with that. Given that the manipulation you need here is fairly involved, it would benefit in the long run to keep it readable, than something clever.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach slightly improving the current answer could be to not perform a `get` without an `isPresent` check. This could be achieved by using `filter` and `map`

```
Map<Part, Map<String, String>> collectingPartMap = partList.stream()
        .map(part -> partDetailsHMap.values().stream()
                .filter(innerMap -> innerMap.containsValue(part.getPartId())) // notice 'getPartId' for the access
                .findFirst()
                .map(firstInnerMap -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(part, firstInnerMap)))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```